# проблема с обновлением .Net Framework

Tags: .net, windows-7

Обновила .net framework до версии 4.7.1. Предыдущую версию .net не удалялa, так как на сайте написано, что это обновление. Установилa .net, перезапустилa пк, в программах .net уже висит, но в папке Microsoft.net>framework новой версии фреймворка нет, есть только 4.0 версия, а сам новый фреймворк находится в папке с .net4>setup cache>4.7 и название папки написано синим цветом. Что случилось скажите пожалуйста

Использую 7 виндовс

[image: вот фото, где у меня расположен новый .net]

Comment: т.к. рантайм не менялся начиная с 4.0 и отличия только в библиотеках и компиляторе, то насколько я помню все версии начиная с 4.0 ставятся в одну папку, т.е. рядом не должно появляться 4.7

Comment: нет. В конфиге я установила сборку .net 4.7.1, но сборка опять производиться в .net 4.0

Comment: https://imgur.com/bOn8i6x вот доказательства

Comment: Если так понятнее - 4.7.1 это не апдейт всего фреймворка, это дополнительные библиотеки, которые ставятся в уже установленный фреймворк 4.0. Сам фреймворк при этом остаётся 4.0. А на скрине у вас папка синяя, потому что она сжата - в ней временные файлы установщика, и у неё в свойствах строит чекбокс «сжать», чтобы временные файлы занимали поменьше места на диске.

Comment: теперь понятно: Фреймворк установился правильно. спасибо